# How to add client certificate data in pom.xml

Tags: spring-boot, maven, soap, wsdl, pom.xml

I need to generate wsdl classes using jaxws-maven-plugin, but the point is that I need to enter basic auth, have cloent certificate with pfx file and password.

How can I solve it? Pls help

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>wsimport-from-jdk</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsimport</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <wsdlUrls>
            <wsdlUrl>https://link/v5.59/service.svc?wsdl</wsdlUrl>
        </wsdlUrls>
        <keep>true</keep>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Basic auth is for username/password authentication or by using an authentication token but usually if you have client certificate that is used directly by the HTTPS connection and not on method level.